# Encrypt data (pjsip)

Tags: c, rtp, pjsip

I want to encrypt data with `Bouncy Castle` in pjsip lib before sending via rtp. Who have worked with pjsip, help me please, I'm not friendly with C, so where should I do that. After some research in pjsip lib files I have found 'transport.c' file with function:

```
static void ice_on_rx_data(pj_ice_strans *ice_st, unsigned comp_id, 
               void *pkt, pj_size_t size,
               const pj_sockaddr_t *src_addr,
               unsigned src_addr_len)
```

Am I on right way?

Comment: Please provide a link to the specification of that language "C/C++". AFAIK, there are only the two different languages C and C++. So only tag the one you are actually using.

Comment: Oh, and that is not a _method_, but a _function_. C does not support _methods_.

Comment: Olaf, could you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find `pjmedia/src/pjmedia/transport_udp.c` in pjsip.

For sending UDP packet pjsip use this function..

```
 static pj_status_t transport_send_rtp( pjmedia_transport *tp,
                   const void *pkt,
                   pj_size_t size)
```

So you have to encrypt your packet in this function. So take the `pkt` and encrypt it.Also if you allow rtcp then you may have to encrypt rtcp packet.That function also be found there. And name is..

```
static pj_status_t transport_send_rtcp2(pjmedia_transport *tp,
                const pj_sockaddr_t *addr,
                unsigned addr_len,
                    const void *pkt,
                    pj_size_t size)
```

So these function can be found in `transport_udp.c` in `pjmedia/src/pjmedia/` directory.

So if you want send encrypted packed you can encrypt the packet there. Also for decrypting a received encrypted packet you may use these functions..

```
 static void on_rx_rtp( pj_ioqueue_key_t *key,
                   pj_ioqueue_op_key_t *op_key,
                   pj_ssize_t bytes_read);

 static void on_rx_rtcp(pj_ioqueue_key_t *key,
                   pj_ioqueue_op_key_t *op_key,
                   pj_ssize_t bytes_read);
```

you can decrypt there.

Comment: while taking **const void *pkt** in transport_send_rtp method, how to open a pkt and and encrypt. If you know any tutorials  suggest it.